# What does "master" mean in "git push origin master"

Tags: git

I'm new to git as a version control system. I tried reading the documentation, but I don't understand what "master" means in this command:

```
git push origin master
```

Can someone explain in very dumbed-down terms?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529497/what-is-origin-in-git (since the linked question implies the answer, but also more includes more detail & references)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the Master branch. The main tree of your control system.

push = push your changes to the remote server
origin = remote Server origin
master = Master branch

If you have another remote branches you have something like "git push origin test" then you push your changes to the test remote branch.

Comment: `git push origin test` pushes the local `test` branch to `origin/test`. Just in case somebody was expecting the current branch to get pushed.

Comment: Let us say, you want to push to a feature/Calculator branch in your repository and calcFeature is your local branch that you just created. what should be the git command? `git push feature/Calculator calcFeature` gave a fatal error saying feature/Calculator is not the correct repository

Comment: @noobcode `git push origin calcFeature:feature/Calculator` should do the trick IIRC. Alternatively, you could also do `git push -u origin feature/Calculator` while you have `calcFeature` checked out

Answer (score 12):

That `master` is the `<src>` part of a [`refspec`](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-5.html).

This means that your local `master` branch will be pushed to the `master` branch of the remote `origin` (`orgin/master`).

---

If you would have specified

```
git push origin master:my_work
```

then you would have pushed your local `master` to `origin/my_work`.
If you don't use the `:my_work` part, then the destination defaults to the same branch as given as source.

---

Just specifying

```
git push origin
```

will push every local branch that has a matching remote branch to that branch per default. **Not just the current branch**.
This is the same as using `git push origin :`.

You can change this default with `git config remote.origin.push HEAD`,
which would push the current branch to a remote branch with the same name.

See [configure-a-local-branch-for-push-to-specific-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109136/configure-a-local-branch-for-push-to-specific-branch) for further details on configuring refspecs and setting `push.default`.

Answer (score 4):

Let me try to explain all elements of this command "in very dumbed-down terms".

```
git push origin master
```

1. `git` you do something with `git` :)
2. `push` you upload your changes to a remote repo = you update the remote repo with your changes
3. `origin` you specify the remote place to push to, usually the particular remote repo where you cloned your directory from
4. `master` you specify the branch which you want to `push` to `origin`

As a newbie you usually will have *only one* remote repo (`origin`) and *only one* branch (`master`), so you can use:

```
git push
```

simply which means the same as `git push origin master` in this case.

Check also `.git/config` in your working directory, it contains info on `origin` and `master`.

Answer (score 1):

> **git push origin master**

- The repository is created in GitHub. So it is the origin. So basically our remote repository(or repo on GitHub is know as
  origin)
- Master is nothing but a default branch in our local repo
- Pushing the local master branch to the remote origin is what makes
  that command

> **git push -u origin master**

- -u stand for upstream
- Using -u is like setting a path for push
- So next time we can use 'git push' directly,
  because now we have set a path for where this push should take the
  current branch to

Answer (score 0):

git push origin master will push your changes to the remote server. "master" refers to master branch in your repository.

If you want to push your changes to any other branch (say test-branch), you can do it by: git push origin test-branch.

This will push your code to origin of test-branch in your repository.